# How to specify order during np.reshape

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, flatten

I have a numpy `ndarray` of shape `(t, n, h, w, c)`. I want to partially flatten it to get an `ndarray` of shape `(t*n, h, w, c)`. However, I want to be able to specify the order that this happens in. Specifically, I want it in '`n`-major order'.

Let's say I have an array `A` with `A.shape = (128, 16, 160, 210, 3` and an array `B` with `B.shape = (16, 128, 160, 210, 3)`. They are almost the same, except the first two dimensions are swapped.

Flattening `B` as follows groups the data the way I would like:

`B = B.reshape(-1, *B.shape[2:])`

`B.shape = (2048, 160, 210, 3)`

Flattening `A` gives an array of the same shape, but with data in a different order.

I have tried the following:
`A = np.moveaxis(A, 0, 1)`
`A = A.reshape(-1, *A.shape[2:])`

I can kind of get it to work doing
`A = np.asarray([A[:, i, ...] for i in range(n)])` where `n` is the length of the second dimension, but I feel like there is a more numpionic way of doing this.

I think that because `moveaxis` (and `swapaxis`) creates a `view` (which is *supposed*  to change the traversal order) that the default order for flattening is based on the original ordering of the data.

How can I flatten `A` in the way that I would like?

Comment: Doesn't `np.moveaxis(A, 0, 1).reshape(-1,*A.shape[2:])` work?

Comment: `moveaxis` does create a view, by changing shape and strides.  But a reshape afterwards may force a copy.  `reshape` does take an `order` parameter, but I don't think it will be useful here.  You want a partial reordering, not a full one.  I think the `moveaxis` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `X.reshape(t*n, h, w, c, order='F')`

Eg.

```py
>>> x = np.array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])

>>> x.shape
(2, 3, 4) 

>>> x.reshape(2*3, 4, order='C')
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])

>>> x.reshape(2*3, 4, order='F')
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

Comment: For a 3d array, your reshape is faster and produces the same thing.  But if `x.shape` is (2,3,2,2) the results are different.  It's not necessarily wrong, but comparing the order `F` view with the order `C` copy will be tricky.